# Application crashes on SensorManager

Tags: android, sensormanager

I am developing an android application in which i want to use accelerometer. 
But whenever i call the method :

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
```

my application crashes.

My code is :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size()!=0)
    {

        Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    x = y = sensorX = sensorY = 0;

}
```

I done search on web but unable to find any solution. I am debugging my application on phone not on emulator. Kindly help me in this regard that why it crashes and how can i fix it.

following are the log cat errors :
05-02 06:40:04.299: W/dalvikvm(9525): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)

```
   05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity ComponentInfo{com.accelerometer/com.accelerometer.AccelerometerActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.SearchManager

   05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)

  05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)

  05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

  05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)

  05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

  05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

  05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

 05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

 05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)

 05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)

 05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.SearchManager

 05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):    at com.accelerometer.AccelerometerActivity.onCreate(AccelerometerActivity.java:24)

05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

05-02 06:40:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post any logcat errors.

Comment: I have edited the post, and posted my logcat errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
```

This returns a SearchManager from `getSystemService()` and you cannot convert a SearchManager to a SensorManager, close but not quite the same...

To get the SensorManager try this: (Taken from the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html))

```
 public SensorActivity() {
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend. I have now solved it by your advice. Thank you again.